# When setting up RAID, what does the option "data protection" mean?

Tags: backup, raid

I'm setting up a RAID and it has the option "data protection". By default it's disabled but can be changed to enabled. I google searched and found [this](http://www.supermicro.com/manuals/other/LSI_2108_2208_SAS_MegaRAID_Configuration_Utility.pdf)

> Data Protection: Use this item to enable or disable data protection.

I'm setting up two RAID 1 arrays of 2 HDs each. Any suggestions or info?

Comment: That option toggles support for the ANSI T10 DIF. See http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-T10E2E/.

Comment: @DanD. but the card was not made by IBM...

Comment: Doesn't matter that's what the option toggles and the link describes what that option enables does.

Answer (score 1):

Per "[The Data Protection Feature / MegaRAID](https://www.broadcom.com/support/knowledgebase/1211161502244/the-data-protection-feature---megaraid)" in Broadcom KB:

> The Data Protection feature is an additional method of preventing data corruption by delivering end-to-end data integrity through the full I/O path from the application to the disk drive. This feature is officially called T-10 Protection Information (T-10 PI) and requires special hard drives with 520-byte sectors.
>
> The feature is essentially Parity which is done internally on the drives that support T-10 PI.

What does that mean, really? Not totally sure yet searching for "T-10 Protection Information" leads to e.g. "[Can someone explain in ''English'' What T10 Pi is for a raid config?](https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/4jwrj8/can_someone_explain_in_english_what_t10_pi_is_for/)" on Reddit with a similar explanation:

> TL;DR It's a method of doing error checking on data that covers the full I/O path rather than just being done by the OS or the storage controller.